# Fast implementation of finding duplicate coordinates

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program which finds duplicate coordinates (`x, y, z`) in a 3D array. The script should mark one or multiple duplicate points with a given tolerance - one point could have more than one duplicate. I found lots of different approaches which among others use sorting approaches.

To try the code I created the following test data set:

```
21.9799629872016 57.4044376777929 0
22.7807110172432 57.6921361034533 0
28.660840151287 61.5676757599822 0
28.6608401512 61.56767575998 0
30.6654296288019 56.2221038199424 0
20.3752036442253 49.1392209993897 0
32.8036584048178 43.927288357851 0
35.8105426210901 51.9456462679106 0
40.8888359641279 58.6944308422108 0
40.88883596412 70.6944308422108 0
41.0892949118794 58.1598736482068 0
39.6860822776189 64.775018924006 0
39.1515250836149 64.8418385732565 0
8.21402748063493 63.5054455882466 0
8.2140275006 63.5074455882 0
8.21404548063493 63.5064455882466 0
8.2143214806 63.5084455882 0
```

The code I came up with is:

```
# given tolerance
tol = 0.01

# initialize empty list for the found duplicates
duplicates = []

# loop over all nodes
for i in range(0,len(nodes)):
    # current node
    curr_node = nodes[i]
    # create difference vector
    diff = nodes - curr_node
    
    # get all duplicate indices (the node itself is found as well)
    condition = np.where((abs(diff[:,0])<tol) & (abs(diff[:,1])<tol) & (abs(diff[:,2])<tol))

    # check if more than one entry is present. If larger than 1, duplicate points exist
    if len(condition[0]) > 1:
        # loop over all found duplicate points
        for j in range(0,len(condition[0])):
            # add duplicate if not already marked as duplicate
            if j>0 and condition[0][j] not in duplicates:
                duplicates.append(condition[0][j] )
```

This code returns what I am expecting:

```
duplicates = [3, 14, 15, 16]
```

However, the code is very slow. For 300,000 points it takes about 10 minutes. I am wondering if there is any faster way to implement this.

Comment: Could you just round the points to some precision and then use a `set` or `dict` to find dupes? This is not the same (two points that are very close could get rounded in different directions) but might be good enough depending on what you really need.

Comment: do u want 2 compare `[x1,y1,z1]` with `[x2,y2,z2]` as whole ? also with serialize like 1to 2 , 2to3, etc

Comment: @tobias_k: Thank you. I had a look on this approach as well. However, finding the duplicates should be as accurate as possible. So having 1 or 2 cm for example makes a difference for my application.

@SurajS: I want to compare each member of the array with each of the given points. So it might be that `[x1,y1,z1]` is a duplicate of  `[x2,y2,z2]` but also `[x10,y10,z10]`. if I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can place points in a grid of `tolerance`-sized cubes. Then, for each point, you only need to check the points from the same cube + 26 adjacent ones instead of all other points.

```
# compute the grid

for p in points:
    cube = (
        int(p[0] / tolerance),
        int(p[1] / tolerance),
        int(p[2] / tolerance))
    grid[cube].append(p)

# check

for p in points:
    cube = as above
    for adj in adjacent_cubes(cube)
       for p2 in grid[adj]
           check_distance(p, p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the nodes upfront, to reduce the amount of loops needed:

```
import timeit
import random

nodes = [
    [21.9799629872016, 57.4044376777929, 0],
    [22.7807110172432, 57.6921361034533, 0],
    [28.660840151287, 61.5676757599822, 0], [28.6608401512, 61.56767575998, 0],
    [30.6654296288019, 56.2221038199424, 0],
    [20.3752036442253, 49.1392209993897, 0],
    [32.8036584048178, 43.927288357851, 0],
    [35.8105426210901, 51.9456462679106, 0],
    [40.8888359641279, 58.6944308422108, 0],
    [40.88883596412, 70.6944308422108, 0],
    [41.0892949118794, 58.1598736482068, 0],
    [39.6860822776189, 64.775018924006, 0],
    [39.1515250836149, 64.8418385732565, 0],
    [8.21402748063493, 63.5054455882466, 0], [8.2140275006, 63.5074455882, 0],
    [8.21404548063493, 63.5064455882466, 0], [8.2143214806, 63.5084455882, 0]
]

duplicates = [3, 14, 15, 16]
assertList = [n for i, n in enumerate(nodes) if i in duplicates]


def new(nodes, tol=0.01):
    print(f"Searching duplicates in {len(nodes)} nodes")
    coordinateLen = range(len(nodes[0]))
    nodes.sort()

    last = nodes[0]
    duplicates = []

    for i, node in enumerate(nodes[1:]):
        if not all(0 <= node[idx] - last[idx] < tol for idx in coordinateLen):
            last = node
        else:
            duplicates.append(node)
    print(f"Found: {len(duplicates)} duplicates")
    return duplicates


# generate random numbers!
randomNodes = [
    [random.uniform(0, 100),
     random.uniform(0, 100),
     random.uniform(0, 1)] for _ in range(300000)
]

# make sure there are at least the same 4 duplicates!
randomNodes += nodes

for i, lst in enumerate((nodes, randomNodes)):
    for func in ("new", ):
        t1 = timeit.Timer(f"{func}({lst})", f"from __main__ import {func}")

        # verify values of found duplicates are [3, 14, 15, 16] !!
        if i == 0:
            print(all(x for x in new(nodes) if x in assertList))
        print(f"{func} took: {t1.timeit(number=10)} seconds")
        print("")
```

Out:

```
Searching duplicates in 17 nodes
Found: 4 duplicates
True
....
new took: 0.00034904800000001845 seconds

Searching duplicates in 300017 nodes
Found: 4 duplicates
...
new took: 14.316181525000001 seconds
```